# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on Android HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpurlconnection, sslhandshakeexception

I've written codes that login and gets HTML of a specific web site.

```
        String loginQuery = Sites.LOGIN_QUERY + "&member_no=" + id + "&password=" + pw;
        HttpsURLConnection con;

        con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(Sites.LOGIN_URL).openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(loginQuery.length()));
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        // Exception in this line...
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

        output.writeBytes(loginQuery);
        output.close();
```

The problem is that above code worked well however after updating to android 5.0, javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException occurs. My device's previous OS version was 4.4.

I've changed nothing my code in the process of updating OS. How can I solve this ?

---

exception log:

```
05-05 14:54:08.821  10855-11793/com.soonoo.mobilecampus E/INFO﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:238)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:158)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:170)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:309)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:242)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:220)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at com.soonoo.mobilecampus.User.login(User.java:72)
        at com.soonoo.mobilecampus.LoginView$Login.doInBackground(LoginView.java:112)
        at com.soonoo.mobilecampus.LoginView$Login.doInBackground(LoginView.java:84)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xaaaf8a00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407743E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:765 0xa9295b25:0x00000000)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: Post the stack trace in your question.

Comment: Have you tried another HTTP client implementation? I had similar problems and I'm now using [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) which works better.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach I just used android's default API and solved this problem anyway. thanks for comment.

Comment: OK, what was the problem?

Comment: Problem occurs since android 5.0 does not support cipher suite that server supports.(https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#ssl)